Django Oauth Toolkit with custom User model
a question here.
I want to use https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html.
But I want the authentication to use different user model (not the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL). Is that possible ? All answers I found just said, to set the AUTH_USER_MODEL to my custom model - but this is not what I want.
Regular admin authentication would use default model of course.
Thanks.

You definitely do not want two user models!  I believe django-oauth-toolkit will work with the default User model.  You can switch to a custom user model midway in a project, but that is not easy!  Why exactly do you think you need two user models?  It might help to point you in the right direction if I knew what you are trying to accomplish.

I solved it another way. Thanks anyway.
